# how to access Target Audiences field using jslink?

Tags: jslink, audience-targeting

Normally you access a field using jslink in the following manner:

```
ctx.CurrentItem.Title
```

but how can I access Audiences field for a given item?
This does not seem to work:

```
ctx.CurrentItem["Target Audiences"]
```

How can I loop through the target audiencies field and display its values using jslink?

Comment: I think audiences are not supported in the SharePoint client object model. Its only supported in the Server Object Model.

Comment: how can I use target audiences in content query web part?

Answer (score 0):

You can access Target Audiencies like:

```
var groupNames; 
groupNames = oListItem.get_item('Target_x0020_Audiences').split(',');
```

then you can loop `groupNames` with comma(,) separated.

Comment: how can I apply this to ctx.CurrentItem?

Comment: Use ctx.CurrentItem["Target_x0020_Audiences"]

Comment: you cannot access them using ctx.CurrentItem["Target_x0020_Audiences"]. I have tried that before, but does not work.